# Create a Non-North/Rotated-Vertically User Coordinate System?

Tags: qgis, postgis, proj

I need to plot 3d PostGIS data into vertical planes for symbolization and drawing vertical cross-section interpretations for mineral exploration models. I have written a short plpgsql function that takes the PostGIS 3D geometry, moves an xy-coordinate to (0,0,0) then rotates it on the z-axis based upon a given rotation(degrees) and then rotates it vertically along the x-axis.  This new geometry is then filtered/cropped by the new/rotated z-coordinates so just the right plane of data can be viewed.  It works and functions well with QGIS but the downside is that it is not a very update able view for any points/lines/polygons that I draw for any particular cross-section interpretation.

Is it possible to write a proj4/proj6 project that rotates the data on the x-axis?  It would have to be version of the Oblique Mercator to provide the horizontal/z-axis rotation?

I know I am asking for a lot but vertical cross-section interpretation is crucial in the mineral/petroleum industry.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xsec_vert_rotate(geometry, double precision, double precision, double precision)
RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
           orig_geom alias for $1;
           x1 alias for $2;
           y1 alias for $3;
           rot_deg alias for $4;
           rot_geom geometry;
    BEGIN
           rot_geom := ST_RotateX(ST_RotateZ(ST_Translate(orig_geom,(0.0::double precision - x1),(0.0::double precision -     y1), >0),radians(rot_deg)),-pi()/2);

           RETURN rot_geom;
    END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.xsec_vert_rotate(geometry, double precision, double precision, double precision) IS 'Cross-Section (Vertical) Rotate: geometry3d, x1/y1 Point Coordinates to move to (0,0,0), Rotation_degress along z-axis to orient data to xy grid system, sets SRID to Zero';
SELECT l.sampleid,
    l.holeid,
    l.sampfrom,
    l.sampto,
    st_z(xsec_vert_rotate(st_transform(st_startpoint(l.bhline_geom), 3158), 375800, 6307000, -65)) AS z_xsec,
    xsec_vert_rotate(st_transform(l.bhline_geom, 3158), 375800, 6307000, 65) AS bhline_geom
   FROM public.lab
  WHERE st_z(xsec_vert_rotate(st_transform(st_startpoint(l.bhline_geom), 3158), 375800, 6307000, -65)) between -50 and 50;
```

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible, but it is not clear what the question is. You ask about proj4 and then post some plpgsql. It is possible to do any rotations and transforms in Postgis, plpgsql. Could you also please format your code, it is totally unreadable like this.

Comment: Code now looks good. But, I am still not entirely clear what the question is. Does this function work and you want it translated to proj4 or is there an issue with the function itself?

Comment: Sorry for the poor code format it was driving me crazy when I posted it.  Yes, the plpgsql function works well for displaying data but it is not optimal to edit data since the view/query is not be updated/edited.  Basically I want to easily draw/edit polygons/lines/points in a vertical plane (i.e. cross-section interpretation)...of course breaking horizontal/normal topology in the process. I was thinking it would be easier to create a custom proj4 projection that could be called in QGIS and then easily edit a PostGIS geometry in it's vertical plane .  I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Sadly, I can't really help with the proj part.